# does Interface Builder automatically instantiate the custom controllers you drag on?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

So I have:

- created a couple of custom
  controllers (add file
  UIViewController subclass)
- in Interface Builder dragged two
  ViewController items from the Library
  to the MainWindow.xib (ie when
  applicationDelegate is, and the main
  window) pane, then set their class
  names to be those of the custom
  controllers respectively

Now that I have done this:

- should this then automatically take
  care of instantiating these
  controllers for use in the
  Application Delegate's
  "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"
  method for example?
- Or do I still need to create these
  controller for the Application
  Delegate *.h and *.m files?
- Or in other words again, trying to
  understand what IB actually does for
  you when you create
  customViewControllers and link them
  up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more detail:   when you add objects to a nib/xib file, what happens is that live objects are created, and then archived into the nib file.   When you load a nib file, those archived objects are unarchived and "brought back to life" with the same settings they had when they were originally archived.   Additionally, any connections that you make in the nib file between actual (UILabel, UIViewController, etc.) objects and proxy objects ("File's Owner") are filled in with the pointers to those newly unarchived/created objects.    Note the special role of File's Owner:   the class that File's Owner  is assigned to is *not* created at nib load time.   Instead, at the time that the nib file is loaded, e.g., with this call:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNib" owner:ownerObject options:nil];
```

any outlets that have nil value in ownerObject (of the same class type as specified in File's Owner) which are hooked up to objects in the nib are then set to point to those newly created objects.

You can use this fact to create self-contained and re-usable bits of View hierarchies that you load and use wherever you want: header/footers/custom cells for UITableViews, reusable-"widgets" that you create/package yourself and use repeatedly throughout the app, etc.   Once you understand this, your Cocoa (touch) view programming skills go "up a level" and creating structured, modular view objects gets much, much easier and more fun!

Comment: thanks this is exactly the kind of thing I'm trying to understand. I'm starting to get the idea a bit - any suggestions re where to read up to get a more detailed/complete overview of what you're describing?  Some question: (1) re "live objects are created" - so does this mean you don't even need to declare/initialize them in your own code?, (2) re "to create self-contained..." do you mean create UIViewController/NIB files just for the purpose of reusing their contents then?  thanks

Comment: @Greg - the Apple Resource Programming Guide has a  Nib Files section with more information.  1) You need to declare a place to save/retain the objects (via IBOutlets, or manually setting the various objects returned in the NSArray from loadNibNamed:owner:options:) (if you don't save anything, why load the file at all?) 2) yes, most useful I've found is in creating a personal "widget library" of UIView subclasses.  For example, I created my own "sliding tab bar" class which is like a tab bar but scrolls, with an interface defined in the nib.

Answer (score -1):

The components in the nib file will be instantiated automatically when they get loaded from a nib as you said.
In many cases you will probably want to have .h/.m files for your controller too, to put some custom code in there.